# Loading data for Table in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I would like to use the example at this url to generate a table: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/473f0cf66196a008cf99

But my return data is not a csv but is loaded from json & here is my structure of data -

It has around 200 array objects. 
Each object's structure has values which again is an object type .

Example of first 2 array objects in the data --->

```
0: Object Id: "1" values: Object Column1: "Row1__Column1_data" Column2: "Row1__Column2_data" Column3: "Row1__Column2_data" 
1: Object Id: "2" values: Object Column1: "Row2__Column1_data" Column2: "Row2__Column1_data" Column3: "Row2__Column1_data"
```

Here is the sample json

```
[{"Id":"1","values":{"Column_1":"Row1_Column1_data","Column_2":"Row1_Column2_data","column_3":"Row1_Column3_data"}},
 {"Id":"2","values":{"Column_1":"Row2_Column1_data","Column_2":"Row2_Column2_data","Column_3":"Row2_Column3_data"}}
]
```

I would like the fetch the 100, 101 and 102 as column names for which I created a different function that creates an array and reads the column names into it . This I use it within th tag.

Now for the data part, how can I fetch the values for the cells  from structure above ..

Comment: Can you include a sample of the json data itself?

Comment: Here is json - "[{"Id":"1","values":{"Column1":"Row1__Column1_data","Column_2":"Row1_Column2_data","column_3":"Row1_Column3_data"}},
  {"Id":"2","values":{"Column_1":"Row2_Column1_data","Column_2":"Row2_Column2_data","Column_3":"Row2_Column3_data"}}
]